# Access Other Computer via ADSL Modem and Router

Tags: router, connection, adsl

My network configuration is like this

ISP -> Modem -> Router -> Computer

and the same goes for my friend. We want to share large files or to access each other's computer. The Passwords to login to the web page of each other modems are known. I mean, we can access each other Modem Web GUI easily ( because we know the WAN IP of each other modem ). The question is how do i access his or how do he access my computer? Is there any way to do so. Remote desktop connection is not working :( Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to both enable port forwarding on each others modems in order for each of you to remote desktop in to each other.

[Take a look here](http://portforward.com/) for more information, you want to forward port TCP 3389
 to the internal IP of your computer. (For example, if your machine connected to the router is 192.168.0.3, you want to forward port 3389 to that).

You can enable Windows file sharing over the internet, however I would advise strongly against that as it can lead you to a world of problems!

What I advise you do for sharing files is look in to a service such as [Microsoft Mesh](http://www.mesh.com) or [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com). Both of these services are designed for sharing files with people and you do not even need your machines on at the same time in order to share as it goes via their service.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) for this, and not monkey with router port forwarding or anything like that.  Essentially Hamachi connects your two networks with a private VPN; this is much more secure than blindly forwarding all traffic on certain ports into your network.